# Custom sort a file in perl

Tags: perl, file, sorting

I'm trying to write a perl script that implements its own custom sort. If the input file looked like:

```
hello
advantage
cat
```

The sorted version would look like:

```
cat
hello
advantage
```

Where if the words are sorted by length, and if two words are the same length then it'd make the normal lexicographical comparison of the two.

Based off things I've seen online my sort line looks something like this:

```
@sorted = sort { length $a <=> length $b } @elements
```

But I'm unsure how I'd add the part where to sort normally if two words are off the same length.

Comment: Do you understand how `length $a <=> length $b` works?

Comment: It returns a 1, 0, or -1 based off of the comparison right

Comment: Right. So, you have to check the 0 case: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that `sort` works is - it sorts positionally based on a comparison. If the sort function is negative, zero or positive.

That's what the `<=>` operator does with numbers, and the `cmp` operator does with strings.

And so it will work just fine:

```
print 2 <=> 3,"\n";
print 3 <=> 3,"\n";
print 3 <=> 2,"\n";
```

Equal length will compare, return zero, and so `sort` will know they're equal. Practically, that does mean the ordering might be random - they're equal as far as `sort` is concerned.

So if you want to implement a secondary sort order, it's actually really easy, thanks to the `||` operator. Because what *this* does is test for 'truth' of the preceding statement - if it's "not true" - in this scenario `0` - it is evaluated and that result may be returned instead.

So you can:

```
print 0 || "fish","\n";
```

Or better yet:

```
print 3 <=> 3 || "fish", "\n";
print 3 <=> 2 || "fish", "\n";
```

So to answer your question - if you want to sort by length and *then* by stringwise:

```
my @sorted = sort { length $a <=> length $b 
                 || $a cmp $b } @elements
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to get this to work and let you know how it turns out.